# Avoid impossible states with a data model for a card game in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to implement the Jass card game in Haskell and would like to make the game state as explicit as possible or avoiding impossible states with types.

The standard variant involves four players. The players opposite each other form a team.
In a game rounds are played until one team reaches the target score.
At the start of each round each player is dealt with 9 cards one player gets to choose the trump, and lead the first trick.
In a trick every player has to play one card. The cards are compared with respect to the leading suit and trump and the player with the highest card wins the trick. The points of the tricks are added to the score of the winner's team. The winner also is lead on the next trick. In a round tricks are played until each player has no cards left.
There is a more detailed explanation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jass#Schieber_rules) and a german explanation on [jassa.at](https://www.jassa.at/).

My data model for the player looks something like this

```
data Player = Player
    { playerID :: PlayerID
    , name :: String
    , cards :: Set Card
    , sendMessage :: Message -> IO ()
    , receiveAction :: IO Action
    }
```

this way I can just use different send and receive functions for like command line or network players.

1. I would like the represent the game as a state machine with a pure update function, however in most states there is only one action from only one player that is valid and so i think that in the update function a big part is just handling invalid inputs.

I don't know what would be the best way to represent these parts of the game state.

2. The Players.

   - My first idea was to use a simple list and rotate this list every time so the current player is always the head. This is easy to do, but i also think it's easy for something to go wrong, like what if the list is empty, or there is only one player and so on...
   - Use an Array for the players and use the index for the current player. This has the advantage that to get to the next player I just have to increase the index. Somewhere i have to use mod to cycle the array but that's not really a problem. I also tried this with XDataKinds to have the size of the array on the type level and so the nextPlayer function can handel the mod. This also has the advantage that for the teams I can just use the even and odd player indices. *But* with this i have to store a extra Map from playerID or index to the cards of the players. So now the array and map can get out of sync.
3. Trick
   I am not sure if i should store a list of played cards and who played them or just a record with the lead, highest card, winner and the value of the played cards and keep track of all played cards in a writer monad.
4. Rounds and Tricks
   This is kinda the same for both, should i store a list with all played rounds and tricks or only the current round and trick and save the sum of the points from the previous rounds/tricks

Comment: You say ‘in most states there is only one action from only one player that is valid’. Could you give an example of an invalid state?

Comment: In most game state's only one player is allowed to play a card from a rather small set of cards. So every card that's not in this set or other action like choosing a trump or any action from a different player is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

There is temptation to have the type checker prove your program is perfect. However, that will become an endless pursuit. There really are not the hours in the day to spend teaching a computer how to be sure what you're sure is sure is for sure for every surety.

What I do is start with *some* way of solving the problem and then learn as I go what the pain points are. Which mistakes am I actually prone to making? In your case, I would implement the game (or part of) in some way I can figure out, and then from that experience I will know how to do it better.

`cycle :: [a] -> [a]` takes a list and repeats it forever. You can do this for your players and take the head of the list forever.

For non-empty lists there is `Data.List.NonEmpty`.

A way to only construct valid game states is to define an abstract data type. Rather than exporting the data constructors for a type, you only export functions of your own definition which can construct the type. That way, you can do whatever (runtime) checking or fixing you want.

Another tool is unit testing. Encoding propositions as types is difficult, especially in Haskell, and so the vast majority will not be. Instead, you can use property-based unit testing to recover a modicum of assurance.

Comment: I already wrote a very simple version that worked pretty good and also use property test. But i would like to rewrite it because there i am using a update function in the IO monad and yeah it's a little mess. But now every time i start to write something i get to a point where something just fells odd, like a maybe that can/should never be nothing. Thanks for the advice, i will just try to stick with one solution and refactor it when i have a better idea, like you said.